# Laravel: What's the advantage of using the asset method in blade pages?

Tags: php, laravel, assets

In some laravel examples I've seen assets being called like this:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{{ asset('icons/favicon-32x32.png') }}" sizes="32x32">
```

What is the advantage of using that method as opposed to doing this?

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="icons/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
```

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/what-does-the-asset-helper-do-in-blade-files?page=1

Comment: `asset` will use/create an absolute url and without asset a relative url will be used and  that won't work at every case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you do the latter, the URLs will not work when you're on any URL that includes a forward slash. E.g. not using `asset` will appear to work fine if you're on the homepage, but if you were on `/search/results` or whatever, the URLs won't be correct (as it'll be looking for `/search/icons/favicon-32x32.png`).

Comment: Aha, now I understand. This is the better answer, I think. The other one just talked about the case of moving the site to a subfolder, which is not so usual. The example you put is the more frequent (using slashes in routes) and it's easy to see how using asset() makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: Anyway, if I use absolute paths, instead of relative, and never intend to move the website from the root of the domain, it'd be the same as using asset(), wouldn't it?

Comment: Well, why would you put your entire website in a subfolder anyway? Aren't you supposed to configure Laravel's "public" folder as the server root (for security) and then use the routes.php file for paths? You can put your virtual "subfolders" there if you need to.

Comment: To answer your questions - yes if you use absolute URLs everywhere and never move your website then you'll be fine. But, for the convenience even on the tiny chance you do change your URL structure (e.g. changing domain name/subdomain or, indeed, putting the application into a subfolder) of not having to update all the hardcoded URLs, you may as well use asset.

Comment: As for the why you'd put it in a subfolder, realistically you generally wouldn't for a normal website. But there are situations where a project may be placed in a subfolder on a greater website as a whole, e.g. it's a completely separate thing - maybe just an API (in the subfolder `/api/`) or an admin area (in `/admin/`) or whatever.

Comment: So basically if he uses `href="/icons/favicon-32x32.png"` then there is no reason to sue assets?

Comment: @Adam if he basically hardcodes the path to `/icons/...` then the reference will always be to `currentdomain.tld/icons/...`. That's usually what you want, so yes, the `asset` helper is not required here. However, it's still best practice to allow Laravel to generate these URLs for you. For example, what if you were to generate and store your assets on S3 or some other CDN? If you use the hardcoded URL you're SOL, but if you use generated URLs, Laravel could potentially generate these CDN URLs for you.

Answer (score 3):

It helps you to generate a valid URL for your assets.

If you use `asset('icons/favicon-32x32.png')`, it will always create application related URL's irrespective of the position of the installation folder of your app in the server.

For example, if your application is hosted in a subfolder instead of the root directory, if you use `asset` method, laravel will create the related path for the asset.

Comment: But isn't that the case as well when using plain relative URLs without using asset()? (with no "/" at the beginning). Relative URLs are also portable if you have your site in a subfolder.