# Blade template (layout file) is working on one file but not working on another file in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a very weird problem. When I extends blade template (layout) to one page, it works but if I extend the same blade template in my other page then it doesnt work. Anyone knows why is it happening ? Any Help please ?

**genericLayout.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>@yield('title') - myUNIMentor</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Free Bootstrap Theme by BootstrapMade.com">
  <meta name="keywords" content="free website templates, free bootstrap themes, free template, free bootstrap, free website template">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Candal|Alegreya+Sans">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/imagehover.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/home">
            <div class="test">
              <span><img src="img/mum_logo_black.png" width="50"; height="35">My</span>Uni<span>Mentor<img src="img/mum_logo_black.png" width="50"; height="35"></span>
            </div>
          </a>

      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#pablo" id="navbarDropdownProfile" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                <i class="material-icons">  </i>
                <p class="d-lg-none d-md-block">
                  Account
                </p>
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownProfile">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a> <br/>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div> 
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                          onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                          document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                          {{ __('Logout') }}
                      </a>

                      <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                          @csrf
                      </form>
                </a>
              </div>
            </li>
          <li></li>
          <li>
          <div class="card-body">
                  @if (session('status'))
                      <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                          {{ session('status') }}
                      </div>
                  @endif


            </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

<section id="feature" class="section-padding">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="header-section text-center">

        <h2> <font color='#5FCF80'><a href="/home">Dashboard </a></font> - @yield('title') </h2>
        @yield('content')

        @if(Session::has('message'))
                  <div class="alert alert-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon"></span><em> "{!! session('message') !!}"</em></div>
                @endif
        <hr class="bottom-line">
        </div>

        <div class="text-center">

      <form class="well form-horizontal" action="/search" method="POST">

              {{ csrf_field() }}

          <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
          <button type="submit" class="btn"> Submit
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>

      </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="organisations" class="section-padding">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">

              @yield('details')

        <div class="detail-info">
            <hgroup>
               <!-- <div class = "text-center"> -->
                @yield('content2')
            </hgroup>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>


  <!--Footer-->
  <footer id="footer" class="footer">
    <div class="container text-center">
        Footer 1
      <ul class="social-links">
        <li><a href="#link"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#link"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-fw"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#link"><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-fw"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#link"><i class="fa fa-dribbble fa-fw"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#link"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-fw"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
      © Footer 2 with copyright
      <div class="credits">
        Footer 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <!--/ Footer-->

  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
  <script src="contactform/contactform.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**The blade file where the above template is working after extending**

```
@extends('layout.genericLayout')
@section('title', 'List')

@section('content')

<p>if have any content that will go here<p>

@endsection

@section('content2')

<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>

@if(isset($find))
    <h1> Found for <font color='#5FCF80'> <b> {{ $search }} </b></font> </h1>

    <table>
  <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Subject</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>Overall</th>
      <th></th>
  <tr>

    @foreach($find as $f)
  <tr>
      <td> {{ $f->users->first_name }} {{ $f->users->last_name }} </td>
      <td> {{ $f->subjects->subject_name }} </td>
      <td> {{ $f->users->city }} </td>
      <td> {{ $f->users->country }} </td>
      <td></td>
      <td> 
        <a href=""> Give Rating </a> <br/>
        <a href="/show-user-profile/{{ $f->users->id }}"> Contact Mentor </a> 
      </td>

  </tr>
    @endforeach
  </table>

@else
<p> No result has been found for <b> {{ $search }} </b>. Please try again with a new search. </p>

@endif

@endsection
```

**The blade file where the layout template is not working when I extend the same template**

```
@extends('layout.genericLayout')
@section('title', 'User Profile')

@section('content')

<p>if have any content that will go here<p>

@endsection

@section('details')

<h3>{{ Auth::user()->first_name }} {{ Auth::user()->last_name }}</h3>
<p>{{ Auth::user()->year_of_study }} <br/> {{ Auth::user()->city }}, {{ Auth::user()->country }}</p>

@endsection

@section('content2')

<div class="text-center">
      <a href="/add-new-review"> Add User Review </a>
    </div>

<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" role="form" action="">

    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="fn" class="signup-control form" id="fn" value="{{ Auth::user()->first_name }}"/>
        <div class="validation"></div>

        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;

        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="ln" class="signup-control form" id="ln" value="{{ Auth::user()->last_name }}"/>
        <div class="validation"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" data-rule="required">
        <label>Email</label> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <input type="text" name="unique_id" class="signup-control form" id="text" value="{{ Auth::user()->email }}" data-rule="email" disabled/> 
        <div class="validation"></div>

        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;

        <label>Password</label> &nbsp;
        <input type="password" class="signup-control form" name="pass" id="pass" value="**********" />
        <div class="validation"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>City</label> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <input type="text" name="city" class="signup-control form" id="city" value="{{ Auth::user()->city }}"/>
        <div class="validation"></div>

        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 

        <label>Country</label> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <input type="text" name="country" class="signup-control form" id="country" value="{{ Auth::user()->country }}"/>
        <div class="validation"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Year of Study</label>
        <input type="text" name="yos" class="signup-control form" id="yos" value="{{ Auth::user()->year_of_study }}" size="30" />
        <div class="validation"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">

    </div>

    @endsection

</form>

@section('content2')

<h3>R</h3>
<p>All R's will go here in this tab</p> 

@endsection
```

Can it be because I am passing an id to see the user profile because even if I create a new blade.php file it does not take the layout and just display the content instead? I even tried creating new files in different `view` folders. This shouldnt be the case if it is.

I did check the console after the page is loaded and I found these errors. The page is not finding the relevant template files

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
imagehover.min.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
bootstrap.min.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
style.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
jquery.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
mum_logo_black.png:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
jquery.easing.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
bootstrap.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
custom.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
contactform.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
font-awesome.min.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
bootstrap.min.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
imagehover.min.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
style.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: What you mean with "its not working"?

Comment: Did you even check your `error_log`?

Comment: @GiacomoM mean the template is not loading on the second file but working perfectly fine on the first one even if I create a new template and extend it to `user profile` page it does not work

Comment: @delboy1978uk there is nothing there it just loads the data of the website without the template being loaded

Comment: I'd start by commenting out all the Laravel stuff in the not working file. ie `Auth::user` and `csrf_field`

Comment: and is your `error_reporting` set to `-1`? Check with a `phpinfo()`, and if not set it

Comment: @delboy1978uk it is set to -1

Comment: @dazed-and-confused what would be point if I comment out all of it ?

Comment: @AsadSajjad To isolate as much code as possible in case there's a problem in one of those lines. Then you'll at least have an idea which way to dig deeper.

Comment: @dazed-and-confused I even tried the `index.php` full code with 0 php code implementation but it didnt work either

Comment: Are they sitting in the same directory structure? ie directory A/working file and directory A/not working file? On a different note, your source lines for the css and js files should be wrapped in an asset() call.

Comment: yes they all are sitting under the same directory structure. I'll do the asset change and will let you know

Comment: @dazed-and-confused I made a copy of all js and css and other files in assets folder and the used {{asset()}} and it worked. Thank you for that but still the navigation bar styling and the div under it is not aligning the text accordingly. Why is that and what exactly assets() does ?

Comment: @AsadSajjad If things aren't aligning correctly, check your classes and formatting, you'll have to play around to get things lined up correctly. As for the asset(), here is a good explanation [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35896303/laravel-whats-the-advantage-of-using-the-asset-method-in-blade-pages)

Comment: @dazed-and-confused thank you helping. It got fixed automatically when I did it this evening. May be I was doing something wrong probably like a typo or anything. Sure. :) Do you want to post an answer fornthe asset that I can marj as an answer ?

Comment: Sounds good @AsadSajjad, glad it worked for you. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **genericLayout.blade.php** file these lines should be changed from:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
<script src="contactform/contactform.js"></script>
```

To:

```
<script src="{{asset('js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('js/jquery.easing.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('js/custom.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('contactform/contactform.js')}}"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`genericLayout.blade.php` is missing `@yield('content1')`.

Comment: tried that but not working either. I even tried to extend another layout but it is still the same